# Silverlight play file from samba enabled remote server

Tags: .net, silverlight, samba

Im currently working on Silverlight app, which resides on our ASP.NET webpage.
I want to populate listbox with names of (audio wav) files that are on remote linux machine.
I also want to be able to play those files using MediaElement.

Im wondering if it is possible to get stream  of remote samba enabled linux server.

thx, for answers

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you enable your ASP.NET application to access the remote Linux machine's files and effectively proxy them. You need to have the files available on HTTP.

Another option may be to run Apache or another HTTP server on the Linux machine and offer up the music that way.

Comment: I got it working creating a WCF service, created a method which returns byte[] array of file an then set it to mediaelement in Silverlight(setSource to MemoryStream created from byte[]). All this works fine on developing machine, but doesnt work when i deploy it to server (IIS7). In my method i get error: could not find part of drive x:\ (on server x is mapped to linux share)